# Vector pop_back

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following function to calculate the distance between two Cartesian points, and the mirror of one of the points about the z axis.

```
inline std::vector< Real64 >
distances(
    MyCartesian const & point_i,
    MyCartesian const & point_j
)
{
    std::vector< Real64 > sumVals;

    // Calculate the distance between points
    sumVals.push_back( pow_2( point_i.x - point_j.x ) );
    sumVals.push_back( pow_2( point_i.y - point_j.y ) );
    sumVals.push_back( pow_2( point_i.z - point_j.z ) );

    Real64 sumTot = 0;
    std::vector< Real64 > retVals;
    std::for_each( sumVals.begin(), sumVals.end(), [&] ( Real64 n ) { sumTot += n; } );
    retVals.push_back( std::sqrt( sumTot ) );

    // Calculate distance to mirror point
    sumVals.pop_back();
    sumVals.push_back( pow_2( point_i.z - ( -point_j.z ) ) );
    sumTot = 0;
    std::for_each( sumVals.begin(), sumVals.end(), [&] ( Real64 n ) { sumTot += n; } );
    retVals.push_back( std::sqrt( sumTot ) );

    return retVals;
};
```

Are there any benefits from `pop_back`, then `push_back`, or is there a better way to replace the last element in the vector?

Comment: Worrying about details like this is over-complicating it. Just do it. You could do stuff with [`vector.back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back), but this will already be just fine

Comment: Yes, what Justin said, but IMO `sumVals.back() = ...` would be clearer.

Comment: You may consider [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) instead of `for_each`

Comment: `std::vector` is helpful when amount of items to be stored is not fixed or is not known at compile time. In your case it would be better to use `::std::array` avoiding (potentially throwing) heap memory allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, using the vector is overcomplicating it.

Write a distance function that you can use.
Something like this:

```
Real64 distance(MyCartesian const & i, MyCartesian const & j)
{
    return std::sqrt(pow_2(i.x - j.x)
                   + pow_2(i.y - j.y)
                   + pow_2(i.z - j.z));
}

MyCartesian mirror(MyCartesian pt)
{
    pt.z *= -1;
    return pt;
}

std::vector<Real64>
distances(MyCartesian const & i,
          MyCartesian const & j)
{
    return std::vector { distance(i, j), distance(i, mirror(j)) };
}
```

Since there's always exactly two results, you might prefer to return a `pair` instead of a `vector`.

Comment: Usually better than a `pair` is a custom `struct`: `struct Distances { Real64 original; Real64 mirrored; };` or similar. The names `first` and `second` are rarely the best options.